# How to update PhysicalAddress object in Invoice?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Here's the update call I'm trying to make. I'm specifying the current billing address id (from the last retrieve) in order to update the PhysicalAddress record. However, the billing address id changes in subsequent retrieve calls.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Mod xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" RequestId="96fbbfedaabe4fe88988aa4de95adf47" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
  <Object xsi:type="Invoice">
    <Id idDomain="NG">196223</Id>
    <SyncToken>26</SyncToken>
    <Header>
      <TxnDate>2013-05-30</TxnDate>
      <Note>New Note Here</Note>
      <CustomerId idDomain="QB">18</CustomerId>
      <DueDate>2013-06-30</DueDate>
      <BillAddr>
        <Id idDomain="QB">000000000000034K</Id>
        <Line1>1234 Lewis Ave</Line1>
        <City>Chicago</City>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <CountrySubDivisionCode>IL</CountrySubDivisionCode>
        <PostalCode>62883</PostalCode>
        <Default>1</Default>
        <Tag>Billing</Tag>
      </BillAddr>
    </Header>
    <Line>
      <Id idDomain="QB">29</Id>
      <ItemId idDomain="NG">145879</ItemId>
      <Qty>10</Qty>
    </Line>
    <Line>
      <Id idDomain="QB">30</Id>
      <ItemId idDomain="QB">4</ItemId>
      <Qty>22</Qty>
    </Line>
  </Object>
</Mod>
```

**My questions:**

1. How do you update a PhysicalAddress record that is a child of an invoice record?
2. Is QB ignoring the ID and creating a new PhysicalAddress record, replacing the original record altogether?
3. If it replaces the old record, is the old record deleted or is it still present?
4. Are there potential issues with just adding a new PhysicalAddress to the update call without an id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using tag(Billing/Shipping) attribute while updating the address. I've tested the same and it is working fine.

[Tag - Tag (or label) that identifies the use of the address. The values allowed are defined in the PhysicalAddressLabelType]

You can test all these using ApiExplorer tool.

https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V2QBD.
Please let me know if it works for you.

Tag=Billing/Shipping is sufficient while updating address. In time of sync, QB associates the id of the parent entity[in this case invoice] and then compares the tag of the address part[shipping/billing]. It deletes the old record and assigns a new internal id. Old record gets deleted..

Thanks

Comment: From his example, it looks like he already *is* using the Tag=Billing node, right?

Comment: Tag=Billing/Shipping is sufficient while updating address. For clarity, I'm adding more text in my original post. Thanks

Comment: Thank you both. I was always able to update the address in QB, but was concerned about possible orphan PhysicalAddress objects sticking around in the system after the update. So if I understand correctly, QB replaces the old record with the new record, and no trace of the old record remains. Also, in updating the address, you don't need to worry about the ID; you just specify the right tag. Correct?

Comment: Correct. The old record gets deleted from db. You don't need to worry about the ID